# Place this enumeration in a table

Tags: tables, enumerate

I would like to put this in a table in a 2-column article with these lines as well as a caption except it should be the column width and it should have a caption at the bottom.

[image]

```
\begin{quote}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Let $M_0$ denote the \textit{null} model, which contains no predictors.
\item For $k=0$, ..., $p-1$: 
\begin{enumerate}
\item Consider all $p-k$ models that augment the predictors in $M_k$ with one additional predictor.
\item Choose the \textit{best}  among these $p-k$ models and call it $M_{k+1}$. Here \textit{best} is defined as having the smallest RSS or highest $R^2$.
\end{enumerate}
\item Select a single best model from among $M_0$, ... $M_p$ using cross validated prediction error, $C_p$ (AIC), BIC, or adjusted $R^2$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{quote}
```

Comment: You can try with `algorithm`, `algorithmic` or `algorithm2e` packages.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just set it as an algorithm, provided by the [`algorithm2e` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,amsmath,enumitem}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,noend]{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\makeatletter
%\def\@algocf@pre@ruled{\hrule height\algoheightrule depth0pt\kern\interspacetitleruled}%
\def\@algocf@post@ruled{\kern\interspacealgoruled\hrule height\algoheightrule\relax\kern\interspacetitleruled}%
\def\@algocf@capt@ruled{under}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]% Some dummy text

\noindent
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@twocolumnfalse
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{Forward stepwise selection}
  Let $M_0$ denote the \textit{null} model, which contains no predictors. \;
  \For{$k = 0, \dots, p-1$}{
    Consider all $p - k$ models that augment the predictors in $M_k$ with one additional predictor. \;
    Choose the \textit{best} among these $p - k$ models and call it $M_{k+1}$. Here \textit{best} is defined as having the smallest RSS or highest $R^2$\!. \;
  }
  Select a single best model from among $M_0, \dots, M_p$ using cross validated prediction error, $C_p$ (AIC), BIC, or adjusted $R^2$\!. \;
\end{algorithm}
\endgroup

\lipsum[2-5]% Some dummy text

\end{document}
```

This looks slightly different than requested, but benefits from the use of traditional syntax for algorithms and is therefore easy to read.